# Strategy for handling dark mode on <10 android devices

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

So I have implemented dark mode in my app and its working well, following the system wide setting on Android 10 and 11 devices.

Is there a way to allow users of pre Android 10 devices to select light or dark theme? My MinSDK is 21

Thinking of a switch in the settings if possible to allow selection and then I use:

`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)`

(is this correct?)

I also guess I should hide this switch on Android 10 onwards devices and let the system deal with light dark mode?  Is there a best practice I should follow for this sort of thing? Is my proposed way of working correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should not remove the switch in 10 onwards, you should give the options "light, dark, system" so then the user can choose what he actually wants or can override it if he has a preferred choice.